# Swifui Realmdatabase Listview crashes

Tags: xcode, realm, swiftui, navigationview

Good evening,

I'm implementing a Realm Database with SwiftUI. 
The Database is made of a table containing "Projects" and a table containing "Measures" (relation one-to-many).
The main view displays the project list and "Measureview" displays the measures related to the project selected.

[image: Contentview]

[image: Measureview]

When I select a project, the measures list is displayed and then impossible to go back, the app crashes (simulator and real device).
Xcode points AppDelegate file : **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffedfd5cfd8)**
I know that 4/5 months ago, some developers experienced this issue but I suppose that currently Apple fix the problem.
Please find below the relevant code :

Realm part :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Combine

class Project : Object, Identifiable  {

    @objc dynamic var ProjectName = "" // primary key
    @objc dynamic var ProjectCategorie = ""
    @objc dynamic var ProjectCommentaire = ""

    let Measures = List<Measure>() // one to many

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ProjectName"
    }
}

class Measure : Object, Identifiable {

   // @objc dynamic var id_Measure = UUID().uuidString // primary key
    @objc dynamic var MeasureName = ""
    @objc dynamic var MeasureDetail = ""
    @objc dynamic var MeasureResult = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "MeasureName"
    }
}

func createProject (_ title:String,_ categorie:String, _ commentaire:String) {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let proj = Project()
    proj.ProjectName = title
    proj.ProjectCategorie = categorie
    proj.ProjectCommentaire = commentaire
    try! realm.write {
           realm.add(proj)
       }
}

//****************************************************************




class BindableResults<Element>: ObservableObject where Element: RealmSwift.RealmCollectionValue {

     let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

      let results: Results<Element>
      private var token: NotificationToken!

      init(results: Results<Element>) {
          self.results = results
          lateInit()
      }

      func lateInit() {
          token = results.observe { _ in
              self.didChange.send(())
          }
      }

      deinit {
          token.invalidate()
      }
}
```

Contentview :

```
 struct ContentView : View {


    @ObservedObject var Proj = BindableResults(results: try! Realm().objects(Project.self))


     var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(Proj.results) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination:  MeasureView(Pro: item) ){
                ContenRowUI(Proj :item)

                }

               }

            }
         .navigationBarTitle(Text("Project List"))

        }  
    }
```

Measure view :

```
struct MeasureView: View {
    var Pro = Project() //= Project()


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
       List(Pro.Measures) { item in
            Text("Detail: \(item.MeasureDetail)")
       }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Measure"))
    }
    }
}
```

Additional information, if I replace Measureview by a simple textview, the behaviour is very weird :
 I select a Project, the application shows the textview and goes back automatically to the main list (project list)
If someone could help me, I would be grateful.
Thanks a lot for your support.

Jeff

Comment: There's a bit too much unrelated code in the question and more importantly, while you've included the code for the two views, what happens when the MeasureView is closed or Back button is tapped is unclear. Do you have code in the Back button? Why is a new Project var be ing instantiated within Measure struct View? Can you clarify?

Comment: Dear Jay,
Sorry for the lack of precision, I'm a newbie with swift.
As I don't know where the problem comes from, I chosen to display a lot of lines of code.
When MeasureView opens, it freezes and the application crashes.
The "back" link is implemented with Navigationlink by swiftui. So I didn't code the Back button.
Regarding the variable Proj in Measure view, I use it to pass the selected project from Contenview to Measureview.
I'm sure that a far more elegant way exists, but it's beyond my level...
Best regards.